# Managing python packages for specific python distribution

Tags: pip, pycharm, python-3.8

I have a bit of a strange case. I have installed pythonn 3.8 on Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Works fine. I have installed for that distribution numpy using:

```
python3.8 -m pip install numpy
```

And I have tested in the interpreter (command line) that it works. I then started a Python project with Pycharm, and specified in that project the same interpreter. It shows indeed numpy as an installed package for that interpreter:

Pycharm Interpreter menu:

[image: img1]

Plus if I run:

```
import numpy as np

print("Hello World")
print(np.zeros(5))
```

everything works as expected. However, Pycharm's auto complete (or interpreter?) doesn't seem to know that numpy exists:

Code:

[image: img2]

Which means I don't get any auto-complete, which is annoying. What do I need to do to solve this? Do I need to append something to python path? Other issues?

Comment: Have you tried to `invalidate cache and restart` in the `File` menu? It sometimes solves such issues.